# Glitching ground textures when running Elderscrolls Online with wine

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gaming, wine

I recently installed Elderscrolls Online with wine, and everything works except the ground textures aren't rendering correctly. In the terminal, I am receiving this error:

> fixme:d3d11:d3d11_immediate_context_RSSetState Ignoring depth bias.

The textures look as if they aren't being cleared on the screen each frame, just rendered ontop of each other. This is only happening on the ground textures as well, everything else looks fine. I am running arch linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching to [DXVK](https://github.com/doitsujin/dxvk) renderer. Works like a charm for me as opposed to default wine one.